# how can I Route to home screen after login using angular4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am creating a simple login screen once it logged in it has to go to home page.

I am having issue in login component I am navigating to to Home but its loading login and home components instead of only home component.

login screen html

```
<input   routerLink="/home"  type="submit"  value="Log In" />
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

routing module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'home',
        component:HomeComponent
    }];
```

[image: login screen]

Comment: Please provide the codes you have done for better help

Comment: It is tough to guess w/o seeing more code.  First off, you only have one route--how is your login form being loaded?  Is the Login form part of HomeComponent?  Based on the code, your 'log in' button will always display above your router-outlet.  Is there anything in the HomeComponent?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. i am doing  bootstrap login component from app module and login form is not not part of Homecomponent and home component does not have any code. after login i am loading homecomponent.